# fonts in tables rendering inconsistently on mobile browsers

Tags: html, css

I am currently creating a desktop site (http://www.robtest.org.uk) that I want to work well with mobile browsers to alleviate the need to create a separate mobile site. Mobile safari appears to scale up the fonts of large blocks of text (which is fine). The problem is with tables which I use for content rather than layout. The fonts in the wide columns are scaled-up to make it readable while those in the smaller width columns are ignored.

My current workaround to render tables consistently is:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {      
    #container td { -webkit-text-size-adjust:100% }}
```

It does work well for pages such as:
http://www.robtest.org.uk/audio_catalogue.html

But it's not ideal for tables like those containing our event details such as:
http://www.robtest.org.uk/events.html

In the latter I'd much rather have all the fonts scaled-up so that the page is consistent rather than just the right hand column.

Is there any way to do this?

Help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks, Dougie :)

Comment: do you have a meta viewport tag in your head?

Comment: No. Should I have? :S

Answer (score 2):

Add a viewport tag in the `<head>` section of your page, it will help prevent device scaling/zooming and give you a uniform look across mobile devices

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: Okay, I've just done that. It now only shows the top left portion of the screen when clicking on a link, but mobile safari still scales the fonts in the tables inconsistently.

Comment: I guess that's because it's a fixed width layout rather than a full responsive design...

Comment: Ya if you are going for a cross-platform look you gotta do a full responsive design, %s & ems instead of fixed pxls