# Why are some rows rendering small in a basic HTML table on mobile browser?

Tags: android, html, firefox, rendering, mobile-website

I have a basic HTML Table. It renders as expected on a PC. But on a mobile browser (tested on firefox and chrome on Android) some rows are large and some are small like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1BEd.jpg). I have uploaded my code [here](http://jsbin.com/dajavezu/) ([QR Code](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chld=%7C1&chl=http://jsbin.com/dajavezu)).

**Why is this happening? and how to fix this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got solution from a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932431/fonts-in-tables-rendering-inconsistently-on-mobile-browsers). Adding a viewport tag in the `<head>` section, will prevent device scaling/zooming and give a uniform look across mobile devices

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```